# Display image based on a output in one window (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface

I have an implementation of k-NN algorithm in Python, that returns the class label of an input. What I need is to show an image assigned to the class label in one window while output is coming (by refreshing the window). Problem is, I am not very experienced in GUI programming, thus I need some resources and assistance to start with. What libraries, books and tutorials could you recommend? Pieces of code would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many libraries allow you add images to your program such as Turtle, PIL.ImagTk and Canvas and you can even use Pygame to a best performance.

PIL.ImagTk and Canvas:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk
backgroundImage = PhotoImage("image path (gif/PPM)")
canvas = Canvas(width = 200, height = 200, bg = 'blue')
canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "C:/Python27/programas/zimages/gato.png")
canvas.create_image(10, 10, image = image, anchor = NW)

mainloop()
```

Turtle:

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()

# click the image icon in the top right of the code window to see
# which images are available in this trinket
image = "rocketship.png"

# add the shape first then set the turtle shape
screen.addshape(image)
turtle.shape(image)

screen.bgcolor("lightblue")

move_speed = 10
turn_speed = 10

# these defs control the movement of our "turtle"
def forward():
turtle.forward(move_speed)

def backward():
   turtle.backward(move_speed)

def left():
   turtle.left(turn_speed)

def right():
    turtle.right(turn_speed)

turtle.penup()
turtle.speed(0)
turtle.home()

# now associate the defs from above with certain keyboard events
screen.onkey(forward, "Up")
screen.onkey(backward, "Down")
screen.onkey(left, "Left")
screen.onkey(right, "Right")
screen.listen()
```

Now let’s change the background

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()

# this assures that the size of the screen will always be 400x400 ...
screen.setup(400, 400)

# ... which is the same size as our image
# now set the background to our space image
screen.bgpic("space.jpg")

# Or, set the shape of a turtle
screen.addshape("rocketship.png")
turtle.shape("rocketship.png")

move_speed = 10
turn_speed = 10

# these defs control the movement of our "turtle"
def forward():
    turtle.forward(move_speed)

def backward():
    turtle.backward(move_speed)

def left():
    turtle.left(turn_speed)

def right():
    turtle.right(turn_speed)

turtle.penup()
turtle.speed(0)
turtle.home()

# now associate the defs from above with certain keyboard events
screen.onkey(forward, "Up")
screen.onkey(backward, "Down")
screen.onkey(left, "Left")
screen.onkey(right, "Right")
screen.listen()
```

for Turtle:
http://blog.trinket.io/using-images-in-turtle-programs/